# Disown won't take -h option

Tags: zsh, nohup, disown

I'm running a command that I now realize I'd like to leave running after I close my SSH session.  I didn't start it with a `&` argument, but I have put it in the background (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>, `bg`).  Now I'm trying to make it keep going after I disconnect.  That's what `disown -h` is for, right?  I've tried `disown -h` and `disown -h 1` (`jobs` shows my job as #1), and I get

```
disown: job not found: -h
```

Why is `disown` taking "-h" as a jobspec rather than an argument?  I'm in `zsh`, if that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bash`, `zsh` and `ksh93` are the shells that have a `disown` command. Of the three, `bash` is the only one that supports a `h` option. Without `-h` it emultates `zsh` behavior (remove from the job table), while with `-h` it emulates `ksh93` behavior (will not send it a SIGHUP upon exit, but doesn't remove it from the job table so you can still `bg` or `fg` or kill it).

You could emulate that behavior with zsh, by doing:

```
typeset -A nohup
trap 'disown %${(k)^nohup}' EXIT
trap 'for i (${(k)nohup}) (($+jobstate[i])) || unset "nohup[$i]"' CHLD
```

So the nohup associative array holds the list of jobs that are not to be sent a SIGHUP upon exit. So, instead of `disown -h %1`, you'd write `nohup[1]=`.

See also `setopt nohup` to not send SIGHUP to any job upon exit.

Comment: First, what's the `%1` in your example, and @mrb's answer?  I think just "1" by itself worked (as in, `disown 1`) when I tried it.  Second, is the option you're referring to `NO_HUP`?  I found `HUP` in the `zshoptions` man page, and I guess you can tack on `NO_` to turn stuff off?

Comment: The `%` is for job specifications. It's not needed for `fg`, `bg` or `disown`, but is for `kill`, so I got into the habit of using it whenever I refer to a job as opposed to a process ID. Yes `setopt noopt` is the same as `unsetopt opt` and underscores are ignored. It is documented.

Answer (score 5):

`disown` on its own is sufficient to let the program keep running after you disconnect:

```
$ command_running_forever
^Z
zsh: suspended  command_running_forever
$ bg
[1]  + continued  command_running_forever
$ jobs
[1]  + running    command_running_forever
$ disown %1
$ logout
```

`disown -h` uses a bash argument which causes the job to remain on the job table and does not receive a SIGHUP when bash receives a SIGHUP (according to bash's `help disown`). This argument is not available with zsh.

Comment: Confirmed this works, but then I don't understand the point of the `AUTO_CONTINUE` option, because AFAIK it is not set.